# RECURSIVE in SQL for more complicated queries (date interval related)

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

Goal: to create a recursive query that gets the last 3 months of a table and sums them for every 3 months back 3 years.

I have a big table but it has sales price as a column and sales date as a column. I want to sum the sales price for all dates in-between now() and the last 3 months then again for months 3 to 6 and again for months 6 to 9 and on all the way back 3 years.

This is the code I have written so far it seems that SDATE1 is iterating the right way but my totpaid is not

```
WITH RECURSIVE PARAMS AS (SELECT '07/01/2023' SDATE, '05/01/23' EDATE), --(this is going to be put in to SSRS so I am hard coding SDATE to with) 

 CteRecursive(SDATE1, totpaid, datereceived) AS (
    Select *
    From (
    select (cast((SELECT SDATE FROM PARAMS) as TIMESTAMP)) SDATE2, sum(totpaid),Datereceived
    From adjudicationresult ar
      where Locations = 'GRE'
      GROUP BY Datereceived
     ) cte
      Where Datereceived <= (cast((SDATE2 ) as date)- (INTERVAL '1 Month' ))
        and Datereceived >= (cast((SDATE2 ) as date)- (INTERVAL '3 Month' ))
--**This is where I think I went wrong trying to get SDATE2 to update

  UNION ALL
    SELECT (SDATE1 - INTERVAL '3 MONTH') SDate3 ,totpaid, Datereceived
    FROM t
    WHERE SDATE1 > (cast((SELECT SDATE FROM PARAMS) as date)- (INTERVAL '12 Month' ))
    GROUP BY t.SDATE1, t.totpaid , t.Datereceived
)
SELECT Sdate1, (totpaid), datereceived
 FROM t
ORDER BY TotPaid;
```

my results are

| SDATE1 | TOTPAID | daterecived |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01T00:00:00 | -49.74 | 2023-05-21 |
| 2023-04-01T00:00:00 | -49.74 | 2023-05-21 |
| 2022-07-01T00:00:00 | -49.74 | 2023-05-21 |
| 2022-10-01T00:00:00 | -49.74 | 2023-05-21 |
| 2023-07-01T00:00:00 | -49.74 | 2023-05-21 |
| 2023-01-01T00:00:00 | 22.08 | 2023-05-07 |
| 2023-04-01T00:00:00 | 22.08 | 2023-05-07 |
| 2022-10-01T00:00:00 | 22.08 | 2023-05-07 |

Or if sorted by sdate1, daterecived

| SDATE1 | TOTPAID | daterecived |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-01T00:00:00 | 1587.84 | 2023-04-01 |
| 2022-07-01T00:00:00 | 285.83 | 2023-04-02 |
| 2022-07-01T00:00:00 | 174746.59 | 2023-04-03 |
| 2022-07-01T00:00:00 | 63322.25 | 2023-04-04 |
| 2022-07-01T00:00:00 | 38465.58 | 2023-04-05 |
| 2022-07-01T00:00:00 | 30848.58 | 2023-04-06 |
| 2022-07-01T00:00:00 | 527.58 | 2023-04-07 |
| 2022-07-01T00:00:00 | 67957.30 | 2023-04-08 |
| 2022-07-01T00:00:00 | 83921.99 | 2023-04-10 |
| 2022-07-01T00:00:00 | 39771.13 | 2023-04-11 |
| 2022-07-01T00:00:00 | 64172.55 | 2023-04-12 |

My Questions are why did it loop for the same days for each sdate1 (ie 2023-01-01:2023-04-01 ect)
and why did iterate over each day instead of summing the whole quarter

Comment: From the question, it sounds like `SELECT sum(totpaid) FILTER (WHERE datereceived >= current_timestamp - INTERVAL '3 months' AND datereceived < current_timestamp), /* other sums with different filter */ FROM tab`.

Comment: There seems to be a bug on SO that requires a blank line before the beginning of a table. The table appears correctly while editing, but isn't formatted after it has been posted.

Comment: Please update the post with sample data and the expected output. Could the desired results be obtained by joining to a generated series of dates instead of using a recursive query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more conventional, and likely better performing, approach is to generate a series of date ranges, then aggregate via those ranges. e.g:

```
SELECT
      r AS start_date
    , r + INTERVAL '3 months' AS end_date
    , sum(totpaid)
FROM
    generate_series(
        CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 years',
        CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months',
        INTERVAL '3 months'
    ) AS r
LEFT JOIN adjudicationresult AS s ON s.Datereceived >= r
                                 AND s.Datereceived < r + INTERVAL '3 months'
GROUP BY
      r
    , r + INTERVAL '3 months'
```

| start_date | end_date | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-07-18 00:00:00 | 2020-10-18 00:00:00 | 300.03 |
| 2022-04-18 00:00:00 | 2022-07-18 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2020-10-18 00:00:00 | 2021-01-18 00:00:00 | 300.03 |
| 2022-10-18 00:00:00 | 2023-01-18 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2021-07-18 00:00:00 | 2021-10-18 00:00:00 | 300.03 |
| 2021-10-18 00:00:00 | 2022-01-18 00:00:00 | 400.04 |
| 2021-04-18 00:00:00 | 2021-07-18 00:00:00 | 300.03 |
| 2021-01-18 00:00:00 | 2021-04-18 00:00:00 | 300.03 |
| 2022-01-18 00:00:00 | 2022-04-18 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2022-07-18 00:00:00 | 2022-10-18 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2023-01-18 00:00:00 | 2023-04-18 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 2023-04-18 00:00:00 | 2023-07-18 00:00:00 | *null* |

See this demonstrated [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/SEB7Yioz)